# LeakCanary Detection for RxJava Observables

Tags: android, memory-leaks, rx-java, leakcanary

I was playing with an empty sample project to test LeakCanary with RxJava subscriptions. To create a memory leak I created the following activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribe {
                    Log.d("Interval", it.toString())
                }
    }

}
```

Every time the device is rotated a new instance of the activity is created and a new interval starts printing a count. The previous counters also continue to print to the logcat. When I dump the heap there is an activity in the heap for each time I have rotated the screen, which is what I expected since the counter is still running for each activity and I have not disposed of the subscription.

*What I don't understand is why a memory leak is not detected by LeakCanary?*

If I instead create my activity as a Java class without using a lambda for the subscriber the leak is detected every time I rotate the screen. In fact, two leaks are detected. First one for the `ReportFragment`, which appears to be an Android framework class and one for my `MainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(
                new Consumer<Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Long aLong) throws Exception {
                        Log.d("Interval", aLong.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Even stranger still is if I convert the Java class to use a lambda the leak is no longer detected!

LeakCanary version 1.6.1, Android compile/target sdk 28.

Comment: Probably because you have a debugger attached - https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#i-know-i-have-a-leak-why-doesnt-the-notification-show

Comment: Debugger is not attached. Leak is detected with the full Java class but not Kotlin or Java with a lambda.